# Dataflow job fails and tries to create temp_dataset on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running a simple dataflow job to read data from a table and write back to another.
The job fails with the error:

> Workflow failed. Causes: S01:ReadFromBQ+WriteToBigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed., BigQuery creating dataset "_dataflow_temp_dataset_18172136482196219053" in project "[my project]" failed., BigQuery execution failed., Error:
> Message: Access Denied: Project [my project]: User does not have bigquery.datasets.create permission in project [my project].

I'm not trying to create any dataset though, it's basically trying to create a temp_dataset because the job fails. But I dont get any information on the real error behind the scene.
The reading isn't the issue, it's really the writing step that fails. I don't think it's related to permissions but my question is more about how to get the real error rather than this one.
Any idea of how to work with this issue ?

Here's the code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, WorkerOptions
from sys import argv

options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = "prj"
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'test'
google_cloud_options.service_account_email = "mysa"
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
worker_options = options.view_as(WorkerOptions)
worker_options.subnetwork = 'subnet'

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    query = "SELECT ..."

    bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)

    bq_data = p | "ReadFromBQ" >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)

    table_schema = ...
    bq_data | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        project="prj",
        dataset="test",
        table="test",
        schema=table_schema,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    )
```

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please share your code for the pipeline? Also, please write out the WriteToBigQuery constructor argument values so we can see if it's from configuration errors. Can you also please double check in IAM that you have thebigquery.datasets.create permission?

Comment: I should say, please double check that the Dataflow service account has that permission.

Comment: IIRC creating a temp dataset is a part of Dataflow's mechanism of reading BigQuery in parallel. Can you try if this works when your service account has the BigQuery write access in your project?

Comment: So adding the bigquery.datasets.create permission fixed the issue, but trying to grant least privilege, I dont really have a way around to give this permission if I want to get the "real" error behind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the BigQuerySource the SDK creates a temporary dataset and stores the output of the query into a temporary table. It then issues an export from that temporary table to read the results from.

So it is expected behavior for it to create this temp_dataset. This means that it is probably not hiding an error.

This is not very well documented but can be seen in the implementation of the BigQuerySource by following the read call: [BigQuerySource.reader()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/752bdfd09bc4175dd9f51a096f81c9e5b0805913/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L534) --> [BigQueryReader()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/752bdfd09bc4175dd9f51a096f81c9e5b0805913/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L1044) --> [BigQueryReader().__iter__()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/752bdfd09bc4175dd9f51a096f81c9e5b0805913/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L1132) --> [BigQueryWrapper.run_query()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/752bdfd09bc4175dd9f51a096f81c9e5b0805913/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L870) --> [BigQueryWrapper._start_query_job()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/752bdfd09bc4175dd9f51a096f81c9e5b0805913/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L411).

Comment: Yes I struggled to find a real explanation, hence why my question ! 
Great thank you for the quick answer and all the help !

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to specify an existing dataset as the temporary dataset instead of letting the APIs associated service account create one?

Comment: You can @Igelkatt see the example below

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the dataset to use. That way the process doesn't create a temp  dataset.
Example:

```
   TypedRead<TableRow> read = BigQueryIO.readTableRowsWithSchema()
    .fromQuery("selectQuery").withQueryTempDataset("existingDataset")
    .usingStandardSql().withMethod(TypedRead.Method.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to specify for python SDK? I'm adding it part of readFromBigquery but it's giving error for selr.temp_dataset.projectId  missing. Please help

Comment: @Soni007 can you post your code? You need to provide an existing dataset name.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have resolved the issue.
We need to set attributes of temp_dataset object of type Datareference. 


    temp_dataset_value = bigquery.DatasetReference(projectId , dataset_id) 
    temp_dataset_value.projectId = projectId
    temp_dataset_value.datasetId = dataset_id